# QWebSocketServer to different thread

Tags: qt, user-interface, websocket, pyqt, qthread

I have an application where i should use QWebSocketServer to accept and parse some socket messages coming from a Bokeh Application. I was able to do that up to now, but now i want to move this whole QWebSocketServer into another thread, so that it wont bother the main GUI. The main Question being does the QWebSocketServer in anyway affect GUI?

The GUI being the parent for QWebSocketServer, i was not able to move it to another thread. Will this work if i inherit QThread class?

I know i should not inherit QThread class and overload run method. I am just wondering if this is possible.

FYI : I am doing all of this in Raspberry pi, and raspberry pi has to do lot of data collection.

Comment: Web sockets operate asynchronously, so what's the point in using threading for this? It sounds like premature optimization, to me. What ***specific*** problem is this causing in the GUI?

Comment: Its not causing any problem at this moment, since GUI is small at this stage, but it will grow pretty larger at later stage. I was just wondering if its possible to move the server to another thread.

Comment: But why bother? What actual problem would it solve?

Comment: Hmm so that the GUI will not be rendered unresponsive, if there is an error in Websocket connection or if there is lot of information to be sent through websocket. Does it really effect GUI?

Comment: This is network IO, which is asynchronous. Why don't you just test things properly and see what actually happens?

Comment: ok, will get back after thorough testing.

Comment: @ekhumoro agreed, especially since the web socket server only handles client connection requests, the actual client connection and thus data transfer is handled by each accepted `QWebSocket`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initialized the QWebSocketServer without parent and moved it to another thread and it worked. I don't know if im doing right.

Im doing like this :-

```
    self.server = SocketServer()
    self.serverThread = QThread()
    self.server.moveToThread(self.serverThread)
```

Here SocketServer is the server class that inherits `QObject()`, and `QWebSocketServer` gets defined in it, with out any parent.

Here is a short snippet of `SocketServer` class:-

```
    onMessageRecieved = pyqtSignal(str)
    serverObject = QWebSocketServer("My Server",QWebSocketServer.NonSecureMode)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.server = QWebSocketServer(self.serverObject.serverName(),self.serverObject.secureMode(),parent)
```

and dont forget to start the thread.

Comment: That looks correct. Your problem was having a parent. You can't move an object to a different thread than the one its parent is running on. I.e. you can only move objects to other threads that have no parent.

Comment: But of course, as pointed out in the comments to the question, this is really just necessary if you want your program to be hard to debug and more complex than necessary. Both usually very bad reasons

Comment: Yes indeed, if we have more threads, the processor spends most of the time switching threads. Instead im just following a paradigm some follows, separating GUI and other actions to separate threads.

Comment: just to be sure: you understood that the web socket server doesn't to anything data related, right? It simply accepts clients connections, which then are handled by web socket objects

Comment: Yeah, i understood, all the data pushing or receiving is done by websocket, this server just accepts client connections coming on particular port on a particular ip address.